# How to Listview with image ? Anyone have any idea how to do that using this code

Tags: android, listview

I already try to display image in ListView, but I got an error at this line:

```
status.setImageResource(R.drawable.inprogress);
```

> *setimageresource undefined for String.

I'm trying to display the image based on the status, if status equals to "Compalint in process" and then the in progress icon will display in the ListView.

This my full code:

```
public class SenaraiSemuaComplaint extends ListActivity {

       String stud_staff_ID;

       private ProgressDialog pDialog;

       JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();


       ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listcomplaint;
       final Context context = this;

       private static String url_listcomplaint = "...";


        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_REGISTER = "register";
        private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
        private static final String TAG_DATE = "date";
        private static final String TAG_STATUS = "status";


        JSONArray register = null;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.listallcomplaint_layout);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    String input = getIntent().getStringExtra("stud_staff_ID");
    Toast.makeText(this, input, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    listcomplaint = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    new LoadAllComplaint().execute();



     ListView lv = getListView();

     lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);






     lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                 int position, long id) {

             String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                     .toString();

             String location = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.location)).getText()
                     .toString();

             String picture = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.picture)).getText()
                     .toString();


                                String input = getIntent().getStringExtra("stud_staff_ID");




                                 Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                         ViewPage.class);

                                 in.putExtra("location", location);
                                 in.putExtra("picture", picture);
                                 in.putExtra("stud_staff_ID", input);
                                 in.putExtra("pid", pid);
                                 startActivityForResult(in, 100);

                            }
                        });






         }

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        if(android.R.id.home == item.getItemId()){
        finish();
    }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }





 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     if (resultCode == 100) {

         Intent intent = getIntent();
         finish();
         startActivity(intent);
     }

 }


 class LoadAllComplaint extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();
         pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SenaraiSemuaComplaint.this);
         pDialog.setMessage("Please wait, Loading Data...");
         pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
         pDialog.setCancelable(false);
         pDialog.show();
     }


     protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


         String input = getIntent().getStringExtra("stud_staff_ID");

         List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("input", input));


         JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_listcomplaint, "GET", params);


         Log.d("List Complaint: ", json.toString());

         try {

             int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

             if (success == 1) {

                 register = json.getJSONArray(TAG_REGISTER);


                 for (int i = 0; i < register.length(); i++) {
                     JSONObject c = register.getJSONObject(i);




                  // keep to variable
                     String pid = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                     String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
                     String status = c.getString(TAG_STATUS);

                     if (status.equals("Complaint in process."))
                     {

                         status.setImageResource(R.drawable.inprogress);
                     }


                     String location = c.getString("location");
                     String picture = c.getString("picture");

                     HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();




                     map.put(TAG_PID, pid);
                     map.put(TAG_DATE, date);
                     map.put(TAG_STATUS, status);
                     map.put("location", location);
                     map.put("picutre", picture);


                     listcomplaint.add(map);
                 }
             } else {



                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run(){

                            String msgs = "No complaint found, please create new complaint.";
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msgs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    });



                         String i = getIntent().getStringExtra("stud_staff_ID");
                         Intent in12 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ComplaintBaru.class);
                         in12.putExtra("stud_staff_ID", i);
                         startActivity(in12);





             }
         } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         return null;
     }


     protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

         pDialog.dismiss();

         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {

                 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                         SenaraiSemuaComplaint.this, listcomplaint,
                         R.layout.list_pendaftaran, new String[] {TAG_PID,
                                 TAG_DATE, TAG_STATUS, "location", "picture" },
                         new int[] {R.id.pid, R.id.inputDate, R.id.inputStatus, R.id.location, R.id.picture});

                 setListAdapter(adapter);
             }
         });

     }

 }

}
```

Comment: Please post the logcat output.

Comment: You cannot set a drawable (setImageResource()) to a String that is the property of an ImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest judging by what you want to achieve that handle this in your Adapter for the `ListView` which would be the adapter you supply to the `ListActivity`.

In the `getView()` of your adapter check the value of your `TextView` and then replace it with a `ProgressBar` either dynamically or by toggling its visibility by letting it reside in the layout for your rows.

Answer (score 0):

it's require to take ImageView than set to Image

```
Imageview img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourimageID).setImageResource(R.drawable.inprogress);
```